# Azure Service Fabric - install previous version of application from Service Fabric Explorer?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to install a previous version of a Service Fabric application using the online Service Fabric Explorer as opposed to having to use a PowerShell script?  In our case, the previous version of the application exists in the cluster and is visible in the list of application versions in the Explorer.

I appreciate any input.

Comment: Feel free to open feature ideas and PRs for SFX here: https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric-explorer/issues

Comment: @MikkelMørkHegnhøj I did :) Appreciate any feedback. https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric-explorer/issues/165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic has been raised a few times around SO, short answer is **no**.

This answer give more details: [Service fabric rollback to previous version from visual stuido or service fabric explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53298526/service-fabric-rollback-to-previous-version-from-visual-stuido-or-service-fabric?r=SearchResults)